# CustomText in Swift UI

Tags: swiftui

I need to make custom text in swift UI, I know I can make extension and do something like this :

```
     Text("ABCD")
                .HeadingXLargeStyle()
extension Text{
    
    func HeadingXLargeStyle() -> some View{
        self.font( .custom("nunito_regular", size: 80))
    }
}
```

BUT I want to do something like this:

```
HeadingXLargeStyle("ABCD")
//I tried this

final class HeadingXLarge: UIViewRepresentable{

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
    uiView.text = newtext
}
var newtext: String
init(_ text: String){
  newtext = text
}

typealias UIViewType = UITextView

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
   let textView = UITextView()
    textView.font = UIFont(name: "inter_bold.ttf", size: 40)
    return textView
}
}
```

but not working.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: “Not working” is not useful to anyone. Explain what is happening. Not what isn’t happening.

Answer (score 0):

For a custom text view, you can simply create one `View` that has a string property to display text like this.

```
struct CustomText: View {
    let text: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .font(.custom("nunito_regular", size: 80))
    }
}
```

If you want to access `UITextView` from `SwiftUI` you need to create a `struct` that confirms to protocol [`UIViewRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable), not a `class`.

```
struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        UITextView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}
```

Now access the above `TextView` like this.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextView(text: $text)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Comment: can we avoid the  @State var text = "" in Content view any how?

Comment: @JSONParser Don't get you but if you want to show fixed or static text then instead of a binding string use a normal string. That's it.

Comment: @JSONParser After trying without binding is it working now?

Comment: not will not work

Comment: Can you specify what is not working? So that I can help and update my answer.

Comment: To use a static text you'll need to pass `.contant("text")` & not a normal string.

Answer (score -1):

1. Find a custom font (can add any .otf or .ttf file to iOS).
2. Add custom font to your app (Go to File ->  Add Files to "Project Name" -> Select file you want to add -> Add.
3. Register your font to info.plist (click on App -> Targets-> Info Tab-> add the key "Fonts provided by application" -> Add the name with file extension of all the fonts as items of the array to Fonts provided by Application.)
4. Use custom font on your code.

```swift
VStack {
    Text("Hello, world!")
        .font(.custom("Roboto-Italic", size: 46))
    Text("Hello, world!")
        .font(.custom("Roboto-bold", size: 46))
}
```